# Rendering animation as image sequence doesn't work

Tags: rendering, animation

I was just wondering if anyone can help with this problem. I have an animation as an image sequence but whenever I try to render it as a video file, it renders the default cube instead. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure how it looks in 2.8 but the rendering properties is a small camera icon at the right.

Open that and go down to the "Post Processing" tab, open it also and make sure the "Sequencer" box is ticked.  

Untick the "Compositor" box to ensure there can be no interference from that.

Answer (score 1):

just open a new blender file and make it by default a video editor, add the image sequence, put your setting and render